# Does Kusto query optimizer re-arrange sequence of where conditions wherever possible?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Lets say I have a Kusto function as:-

```
myfunction()
{
   <some logic> | where <some condition>
}
```

Now lets say I am calling this function as

```
myfunction() | where < some condition >
```

If I had a choice maybe I would place this second condition (the one being applied on top of the function) at the earliest possible location in the function itself. But this is not feasible because this second condition is more like filtering on a time column , so different users may call this function and filter on different time period. What I am trying to understand is , will Kusto optimizer push this second condition at the earliest possible place in the function itself while executing? Because that would have been most efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the applicable optimizations will happen since during the creation of the query plan the functions are getting fused in the context of the full query. Of course, this is dependant on whether the filter can be pushed based on the actual query itself and the different operators used in the function, but this should be no different than when writing the query using a function or writing it directly as a single query.

Comment: Is there any admin command to know exactly how many extents a query will scan or some clue about that so that we can compare between the two approaches to see if Kusto is actually able to push a condition upstream in a particular case (since it may not always be possible , depending on the logic)?

Comment: Yes 
.show queries  | take 1 | project ScannedExtentsStatistics